Log-rotate is failing with error: unable to open /presto_webapp/log/production.log.1 for compression
Logrotate is not working due to permission issue.
● logrotate.service - Rotate log files
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/logrotate.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-04-23 00:00:08 UTC; 5h 17min ago
TriggeredBy: ● logrotate.timer
       Docs: man:logrotate(8)
             man:logrotate.conf(5)
    Process: 208154 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 208154 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 23 00:00:08 ip-172-31-11-23 systemd[1]: Starting Rotate log files...
Apr 23 00:00:08 ip-172-31-11-23 logrotate[208154]: error: unable to open /presto_webapp/log/production.log.1 for compression
Apr 23 00:00:08 ip-172-31-11-23 systemd[1]: logrotate.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 23 00:00:08 ip-172-31-11-23 systemd[1]: logrotate.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 23 00:00:08 ip-172-31-11-23 systemd[1]: Failed to start Rotate log files

Permission of log files are as below
-rw-rw-rw- 1 ubuntu root   7.1G Apr 23 05:39 production.log
-rw-rw-rw- 1 ubuntu root   911M Mar 11 10:01 production.log.1

Permission of log directory is
drwxr-xr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu       279 Mar 18 05:15 log

Config for log rotate is as below
/presto_webapp/log/*.log {
  daily
  missingok
  rotate 180
  compress
  delaycompress
  notifempty
  copytruncate
}

Please help in fixing this issue.

What is the permissions/ownership/mount state of the directory /presto_webapp/log/? Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld, a bash script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Is the path correct? What does ls -l /presto_webapp show?
